# Creating .h file with definitions using powershell and cmd

Tags: windows, git, file, powershell, cmd

I'm newb in powerShell and in cmd, sorry.
I'm trying write script that can generate define like this

```
#define VERSION "a89aa153a054b865c0ef0a6eddf3dfd578eee9d2"
```

in VERSION i want to set the parameter from next source

```
.git\refs\heads\project
```

I'm tried next cmd script, but i have problems with " character, i can't escape it

```
echo #define VERSION \" > ver.h
type .git\refs\heads\project >> ver.h
echo \" >> ver.h
```

Also i'm tried use script from that post http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/29/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-and-extract-all-the-text-enclosed-in-double-quote-marks.aspx

but i have a problems when i'm trying to run it. 
i'm created file writeDefine.ps1

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Scripts\DefineTemplate.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strText = ""
    strCharacter = objFile.Read(1)
    If strCharacter = Chr(34) Then
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
           strNewCharacter = objFile.Read(1)
           If strNewCharacter = Chr(34) Then
               Exit Do
           End If
           If strNewCharacter <> "" Then
               strText = strText & strNewCharacter
           End If
        Loop
        Wscript.Echo strText
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
```

i want to read template and insert VERSION between " characters and write that text to the "ver.h", but 
i have got an error

```
D:\writeHeader.ps1:4 symbol:67
+ Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Scripts\DefineTemplate.txt", <<<<  ForReading)
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

DefineTemplate.txt

```
#define VERSION ""
```

Please, help me. Thanks!

Comment: The code you have is vbscript and no powershell. Rename it as  writeDefine.vbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script sample is VBScript, not Powershell. Thus, you cannot execute it on Powershell. You can, however, execute it via invoking `cscript`. There is also `wscript` that executes VBScript, but it is used for graphics: popup windows and such. Rename the file as `.vbs`  and run it. Like so,

```
cscript d:\writeHeader.vbs
```

Cmd.exe uses the hat char as escape. Like so,

```
C:\temp>echo #define VERSION ^" > ver.h
C:\temp>type ver.h
#define VERSION "
```

Edit: As per how to create the header on a single line, some trickery must be invoked. This would be much more simple in Powershell, but here goes.

```
:: Assume git data is in git.dat and it doesn't contain a newline
echo ^"> quote.txt
<nul set /p d=#define VERSION ^"> ver.h
copy /y ver.h+git.dat+quote.txt ver2.h
type ver2.h
#define VERSION "0x000..."
```

... But I'd still do this in Powershell. Like so,

```
$git = cat .git\refs\heads\project # Read the git project file
$str = $("#define VERSION `"{0}`"" -f $git) # Build a formatted string
set-content -LiteralPath ver.h -value $str # Write the string to a file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! About cmd. That script generates 3 lines of code. Could you tell me, how can i write it in one line?